# Replace in nested JSON string value '\\n' with '\n'

Tags: javascript, json, string, replace

I have nested JSON and in some string value as part of the string `\\n`. I need to replace it with `\n` and return the object.

My brain is washed, cos I'm trying it for the whole day and can't see the error.

```
var data = {
  "d": {
    "name": "Some text",
    "style": [
      {
        "title": {
          "showtitle": true,
          "en": "Need help?",
          "de": "\\nBrauchen Sie\\nHilfe?",
          "font": "Helvetica-Semibold"
        }
      },
      {
        "subtitle": {
          "showtitle": true,
          "en": "English Text",
          "de": "\\nGerman\\nText",
          "font": "Helvetica-Semibold"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};

      // Replace '\\n' with '\n' in the JSON data
      function update(object) {
          Object.keys(object).forEach(function (k,v) {
              var v = object[k];
              if (object[k] && typeof object[k] === 'object') {
                  return update(object[k])
              }
              if (object[k] === 'en' || object[k] === 'de') {
                  object[k] = v.replace(/\\n/g, '\n');
              }
              console.log('Key: ',k);
              console.log('Value: ',v);
          });
          return object;
      }

      data = update(data);
      console.log('Data: ', data)
```

Why the values are not updated? Where is the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to test for `k`, not `object[k]` on this line:

```
   // testing for the value
   if (object[k] === 'en' || object[k] === 'de') {
     object[k] = v.replace(/\\n/g, '\n');
   }

   //testing for the key
   if (k === 'en' || k === 'de') {
     object[k] = v.replace(/\\n/g, '\n');
   }
```

```js
var data = {
  "d": {
    "name": "Some text",
    "style": [{
        "title": {
          "showtitle": true,
          "en": "Need help?",
          "de": "\\nBrauchen Sie\\nHilfe?",
          "font": "Helvetica-Semibold"
        }
      },
      {
        "subtitle": {
          "showtitle": true,
          "en": "English Text",
          "de": "\\nGerman\\nText",
          "font": "Helvetica-Semibold"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};

// Replace '\\n' with '\n' in the JSON data
function update(object) {
  Object.keys(object).forEach(function(k, v) {
    var v = object[k];
    if (object[k] && typeof object[k] === 'object') {
      return update(object[k])
    }
    if (k === 'en' || k === 'de') {
      object[k] = v.replace(/\\n/g, '\n');
    }
  });
  return object;
}

data = update(data);
console.log('Data: ', data)
```

Also, for what it's worth, here's a slimmer version of your function

```
const update2 = object => {
  for (let o in object) object[o] = typeof object[o] === "string" ? object[o].replace(/\\n/g, '\n') : update2(object[o])
  return object;
}
```

```js
var data = {
  "d": {
    "name": "Some text",
    "style": [{
        "title": {
          "showtitle": true,
          "en": "Need help?",
          "de": "\\nBrauchen Sie\\nHilfe?",
          "font": "Helvetica-Semibold"
        }
      },
      {
        "subtitle": {
          "showtitle": true,
          "en": "English Text",
          "de": "\\nGerman\\nText",
          "font": "Helvetica-Semibold"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
const update2 = object => {
  for (let o in object) object[o] = typeof object[o] === "string" ? object[o].replace(/\\n/g, '\n') : update2(object[o])
  return object;
}

console.log('Data2: ', update2(data))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem because of `if (object[k] === 'en' || object[k] === 'de')`  should be `if (k === 'en' || k === 'de')`:

```js
var data = {
  "d": {
    "name": "Some text",
    "style": [
      {
        "title": {
          "showtitle": true,
          "en": "Need help?",
          "de": "\\nBrauchen Sie\\nHilfe?",
          "font": "Helvetica-Semibold"
        }
      },
      {
        "subtitle": {
          "showtitle": true,
          "en": "English Text",
          "de": "\\nGerman\\nText",
          "font": "Helvetica-Semibold"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};

      // Replace '\\n' with '\n' in the JSON data
      function update(object) {
          Object.keys(object).forEach(function (k,v) {
              var v = object[k];
              if (object[k] && typeof object[k] === 'object') {
                  return update(object[k])
              }
              if (k === 'en' || k === 'de') {
                  object[k] = v.replace(/\\n/g, '\n');
              }
              //console.log('Key: ',k);
              //console.log('Value: ',v);
          });
          return object;
      }

      data = update(data);
      console.log('Data: ', data)
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue lies in the condition `if (object[k] === 'en' || object[k] === 'de')` inside your `update` function. This condition is checking if the current property value is equal to the string `'en'` or `'de'`, which is not what you intended.

Here's the corrected code:

```js
// Replace '\\n' with '\n' in the JSON data
function update(object) {
  Object.keys(object).forEach(function (k) {
    var v = object[k];
    if (v && typeof v === 'object') {
      return update(v);
    }
    if (k === 'en' || k === 'de') {
      object[k] = v.replace(/\\n/g, '\n');
    }
    console.log('Key: ', k);
    console.log('Value: ', v);
  });
  return object;
}

data = update(data);
console.log('Data: ', data);
```

Now when you run the code, it will correctly replace `\\n` with `\n` in the nested JSON string values.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

You could do the transform in one line using a JSON [replacer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#parameters) function. When the property name is "de" and the value is a string, the function replaces all "\\n" with "\n".

**Snippet**

```js
let data = {"d":{"name":"Some text","style":[{"title":{"showtitle":true,"en":"Need help?","de":"\\nBrauchen Sie\\nHilfe?","font":"Helvetica-Semibold"}},{"subtitle":{"showtitle":true,"en":"English Text","de":"\\nGerman\\nText","font":"Helvetica-Semibold"}}]}}

data = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data, (k,v) => 
    k === "de" && typeof v === "string" ? v.replaceAll("\\n", "\n") : v ))

console.log(data);
```

Comment: You answered quite the same as me, but quicker. +1